# how to encase the page numbers in table of content with parenthesis

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a way to encase the page numbers in the table of content with parenthesis?

For example, the entry of the table is in the format:

```
1.1 section name ............ 12
```

what I expect is:

```
1.1 section name ............ (12)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which `documentclass` are you using? Could you please add a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: Should the used page numbers in the header/footer of your pages also use this parenthesis or not?

Comment: I have seen books where the page numbers are enclosed in boxes or fleurons  (like `<- 23 ->` where `<-` and `->` represent fleurons). Page numbers in the ToC would look horrible if presented like this, so in the ToC it would be just `23`. Keep the ToC page numbers simple whatever you want to do in the body of the document.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I was writing a report and thus, such a formation is required. Eventually, I figured out the solution and will leave an answer in case others like me get this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps encase the page numbers:
1. include package tocloft
2. redefine the following variable,

```
\let\origcftsecpagefont\cftsecpagefont
\let\origcftsecafterpnum\cftsecafterpnum
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{(\origcftsecpagefont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\origcftsecafterpnum)}
```